# Firebase iOS Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I keep getting the error in the title when I run my Firebase application. I believe it is preventing me from executing database queries. For example `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser` is `nil` after logging in.

After research, I believe I have to add a keychain to my project. When I turn on keychain sharing in (xCode -> targets -> capabilities) I get the error in the screen cap below.

[image]

Do I need to add some sort of certificate in Keychain Access (application)?

I'm not using the messaging feature, so I don't think I need to add the .p12 certificate suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443334/failed-to-fetch-default-token-error-domain-com-firebase-iid-code-501-null).

Do I need to add some sort of keychain in the Firebase console?

I've confirmed that my BundleID is correct.

Do I need to change something here:

[image]

I have followed all the setup steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/xvjyJUMFL1Y/rhsF7EQEBQAJ

There's a bug in my version of Firebase -- `pod update` resolved this issue