# Is replacing the GoogleService-Info.plist enough to make someone else's app work with my bundle identifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, firebase

I recently got an app from an iOS developer, and it is working with his bundle identifier in xCode. but when I change the bundle identifier to mine, it stops working(database is not connecting). What should I do to make it work? Making a new Firebase account and use my bundle identifier to get a new `GoogleService-Info.plist` and replace it with his `GoogleService-Info.plist` is enough ? (I did that too but still not connecting to the database) what have I missed ?

**UPDATE**

I want to connect to my new empty database that comes with the new firebase account , not the previous database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying so much time I found the error it was

`FIRAuthErrorCodeOperationNotAllowed = 17006`

*Indicates that email and password accounts are not enabled. Enable them in the Auth section of the Firebase console*

to get rid of this all I have to do was go to,

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/myproject/authentication/providers

and select Sign-In method and **enable email and password**

Answer (score 1):

If you read the `GoogleService-Info.plist` the `DATABASE_URL` should be different in two files. Thats why you can't connect to the previous database. You can export data from the first one and then import those json to the new database. Is this solution okay for your case?

**Updated**

Okay, step by step. There are error messages showing in the XCode console. Do you know how to find them? I created a Firebase file, replaced a new plist. And then I run the app, when I try to sign up. It shows a pop up "Problem with creating a new user, Problem connecting to database, Pleaes try again later". But the important thing is! This is not the error code. When you look at the XCode console, it shows:

```
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=501 "(null)" UserInfo={msg=Missing device credentials. Retry later.}
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to retrieve the default GCM token after 5 retries
```

Then you can google it.
[How to fix Failed to fetch default token error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443334/how-to-fix-failed-to-fetch-default-token-error)

Comment: I want to connect to my new empty database, not the previous one , thanks for the answer

Comment: Base on your code you provide to us @ the last question, the code should be fine. Yes you need a plist from the new account. And I doubt that if you really cannot connect to the new database. Any error code? Or may be it does connect to the new one but nothing shows up just because the database is empty.

Comment: I can't even sign up, if the database is connecting , I should be able to sign up right ? there is no error code showing , please try changing the firebase account if possible

Comment: I seems like you need to do a lot of effort to create those token. The official document is a good starting point. https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup. And feel free to ask question @ Stackoverflow. Have a nice day.

Comment: actually , I did that earlier , I enabled keychain sharing , but even after that i get the "cannot connect to the database"

Comment: The GCM is the most troublesome part :'( https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs. Gook luck bro

Comment: thank you bro !! means a lot ! you made my day :) @PangHoMing