# Ionic2 iOS white screen of death

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, wsod

I have an Ionic2 application that runs on android and browser without a problem but gives white screen of death when running on ios. Unfortunately I don't have any apple product here so what are my options to know what is causing this?

I've tried to run the app in safari for windows. It throws errors but the last safari for windows is 5.1.7, so I think it's just too old to run this.

The customer tries to run my application on iOS 8.4.1. Can I set some properties for typescript or cordova to generate code that this version is able to run?

Here is a log from the device: http://pastebin.com/AeChDngK

Comment: Go to safari open up your development console find your phone and look at the console logs there. The xcode log doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

I think The error is clear

```
2017-01-26 13:54:44.632: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.firebase.iid error 1001.)"
```

You can get the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443334/how-to-fix-failed-to-fetch-default-token-error)

Comment: This message is not connected to the white screen of death, and its just a Warning. The app is running further.