# ios10, Swift 3 and Firebase Push Notifications (FCM)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am struggling to display my push notifications that I am sending to my device from the FCM notification console.  I can see the device is receiving the notification because I can see the message I send "test8"

```
Connected to FCM.
%@ [AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = test8;
    e = 1;
},
```

But it does not matter if my app is in the foreground or background I don't get the notification displayed.

I have added "Required background modes - App downloads content in response to push notifications" to the info.plist.  My certificates are correct and I have no issue generating a token. My app is receiving the notifications but just not displaying them.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(
                authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_,_ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]

        FIRApp.configure()

        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                         name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification,
                                                         object: nil)

        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }

    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
```

I having been trying to research and solve this issue on my own but I am having issues.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did u solve ur issue, I am not receiving notifications in Xcode 8.1 swift 2.3.since couple of days i am trying from server side i am receiving and also when i send firebase console i am getting .Please can u help me .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside method **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken**, add the following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Unknown)

    print("tokenString: \(tokenString)")
}
```

And do not forget to enable **Push Notifications** inside **Capabilities**.

Comment: i added the following because I am using swift syntax but it did not solve the issue I am having.  I do appreciate the suggestion though.            func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    }

Comment: @Paul_D Add this line to your Info.plist file:
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled and set the Boolean value to NO

Comment: Thank you for the help Gustavo.  I am still struggling I am getting the following error...  <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)".   I am getting the notifications just not displaying them.  I am searching google and trying everything I can to resolve this issue.  I know I have correctly uploaded my .p12 certificated to the Firebase console under project settings, and the under cloud messaging.    Push notifications and (background mode --> remote notifications) are both enabled.

Comment: @Paul_D yes Paul, it's a little difficult to help in here because you need to follow several steps. I did a video with a tutorial, but it's in portuguese and it's not in the web yet.
But did you import the JSON generated by Firebase in your application?

Comment: Is it possible to upload a screenshot of your Info.plist? And your .entitlements file?

Comment: Gustavo I followed your instructions and the notifications are now working.  I had to follow you direction and then I uninstalled the app from my device, cleaned the project, rebuild and then reinstalled it on my phone.  I am now able to receive notifications while my app is running in the foreground and background.  Thank you for your help.  I really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @Paul_D Glad to help :)

Comment: Anyone converted this into Swift 3 code?
error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<CChar>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer)'
-so there is a whole new way for UnsafeRawPointer

Comment: Yes, it is working, BUT: there is a small problem in the original code: missing     application.registerForRemoteNotifications() in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions(). It should be ALSO called for iOS 10.

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa.. I don't know what wrong with my code http://stackoverflow.com/q/41198651/5362916 I am not receiving notifications in Xcode 8.1 swift 2.3.since couple of days i am trying from server side i am receiving and also when i send firebase console i am getting.These messages are not getting from top .Please can u guide me

Answer (score 3):

You need to move

```
 application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

it should not be inside the else.

```
// [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(
            authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)            
    }

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

[See following commit in Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/commit/03d793fa1ac1ffb95bead8606ae02a6f99d67e7a)

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem!! The original source code must be updated!!

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem too. However you should update your code for swift 3.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the missing `entitlements` file, so in the `Capabilities` of your project, you have to click fix issue. Xcode will setup the file for you.

[image]

Comment: I reckon this would be the fix for most Xcode 8+ users! cheers