# Why I do not get push notifications from Firebase in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I set this code in my AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate { 

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(authOptions, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool, error: NSError?) in
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
        })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], categories: nil))
}
```

Also this parts:

```
internal func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print(userInfo)
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    //Handle the notification
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    //Handle the notification
}
```

I also uploaded development APNs into the Apple Developers. In the Firebase console it writes that notification was successfully sent, but I do not get any push notification. Can anyone please help me to detect where my mistake is?

I have worked on it for 3 days. Searched a lot, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `FIRApp.configure()` to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
2. Add `FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
           if error != nil {
               print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
           } else {
               print("Connected to FCM.")
           }` to the end of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
3. Implement the `FIRMessageDelegate` function

   ```
   func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {

       print(remoteMessage.appData)
   }
   ```
4. Add `FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)` to `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`

The finishing code should look like this:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }


    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {

    print("applicationReceivedRemoteMessage ")
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}
```

Comment: nothing happens again. Firebase writes sending success, but I do not get anything =/

Comment: Can you screen cap your "Compose message" screen from the Firebase console? Did you set the FCM registration token correctly?

Comment: And did you get the ""Connected to FCM." from the XCode console?

Comment: okay cool. That means your configuration on Firebase console is working. The broken part may be your app doesnt receive notification from APNS server. So did your enable "Push Notifications" @ XCode, create a Development provisioning profile @ Developer.apple.com?

Comment: So, my Push Notifications are work, how I just noticed. But it does not work on background mode =/

Comment: congrat:) you need to turn on the "Remote notifications" @ XCode project @ Capabilities. This part should be easy to google. Have a nice day.

Comment: Is this only for IOS 9 and bellow? 10 will be different?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking, check the last answer here: [ios10, Swift 3 and Firebase Push Notifications (FCM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729249/ios10-swift-3-and-firebase-push-notifications-fcm/40444932#40444932)

- Check your push notification entitlement and switch it on. Target > Capabilities > Push notifications.